# parsing jscript within sql server 2008

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008, jscript.net

Is there a way to parse jscript which is stored in a server table. I am looking for something like eval(jscript function).

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about what you're trying to do (and why)? You ask about parsing jscript, but my understanding of the `eval()` method is that it executes the code passed as the first argument rather than simply parsing it.

Comment: Ed, my bad.. Yes, I want to  execute jscript code within  the sql server to execute some rules/constraints wrtten in Jscript, thats is stored along with some attributes (parameters) that get fed into jscript function (normaly at the client end), but some jscript function do not get executed at the client-end because the constaint/rule(jscript) determines they are either hidden or disabled. If I can execute jscript rule/constraint within the server; I can determine whether the field/script in question needs to be sent to the client or not

Answer (score 0):

Well, using some hacks like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Managed_Code_in_SQL.aspx) you can run managed code inside SQL server and upo that, use the JavaScriptSerializer class to deserialize the JSON objects. If you have JavaScript as a plain code, well, it would be funny If one was able to run that inside SQL :)